# select rows with all min values and next max value of given value

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I need to fetch data from postgresql, where I need to select rows on below condition.

```
id  type  total_quantity created_dttm [desc]

1    1    12            27-Jun-2021
2    1    32            26-Jun-2021
3    1    52            25-Jun-2021
```

need to get all rows matching the given value in a query. if i give value as 24 , then I need to get all rows <= 24 and next max value of 24 ..order by created_dttm desc order

so I need to get only two rows ..

```
id  type  total_quantity created_dttm [desc]

1    1    12            27-Jun-2021
2    1    32            26-Jun-2021
```

I tried sum of two columns, but this will not work, since i am looking for rows between a value range, and with condition to select all rows less than given value + select next max value of given value.. for the given type...

Edit :- the query has to fetch based on type  and order by created_dttm desc

Comment: What is  "next max value" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `MIN()` window function you can get for each `type` the min `total_quantity` that is greater than `24`:

```
SELECT id, type, total_quantity, created_dttm
FROM (
  SELECT *, MIN(total_quantity) FILTER (WHERE total_quantity > 24) OVER (PARTITION BY type) qty
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE total_quantity <= qty
```

If you want results for `type = 1` only:

```
SELECT id, type, total_quantity, created_dttm
FROM (
  SELECT *, MIN(total_quantity) FILTER (WHERE total_quantity > 24) OVER () qty
  FROM tablename
  WHERE type = 1
) t
WHERE total_quantity <= qty
```

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE type = 1 
  AND total_quantity <= (SELECT MIN(total_quantity) FROM tablename WHERE total_quantity > 24)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=88f6bfb5a2902def95aef3ebea18d946).

Comment: this query get me all type rows , but i need to get for one type..

Comment: @pappu_kutty then add a WHERE clause: WHERE type = 1

Comment: i tried the query with type=1, but it is not returning any rows.. it gives me empty

Comment: @pappu_kutty you accepted an answer that returns wrong results. Now you are telling me that my answer does not return your expected results? I provided a demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=32fd9df600380098fccabf2348120e73

Comment: sorry.. this query is working perfect.. i think both query works as i wanted.

Comment: @pappu_kutty no, the answer that you accepted does not work at all: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=bce0a1b7b23a1c2d31666f06d978c464

Comment: i tested both query in my pgadmin both query works as expected, but i dont know why it is not working in fiddle..

Comment: @pappu_kutty this is not possible. You posted sample data for your requirement. For this sample data the answer that you accepted does not work. Either you posted wrong sample data in which case my answer would not work for your actual data or your sample data is correct in which case the answer that you accepted is wrong.

Comment: i tested, both query works without created_dttm order, but if i add order by craeted_dttm asc, both query doent works..

Comment: @pappu_kutty create a fiddle with sample data here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5 to prove that my queries don't work and that the answer that you accepted works.

Comment: forpas, i need rows from last entered based on created_dttm asc, in this case both the solutions doesnt work..

Comment: @pappu_kutty what do you mean by *last entered based on created_dttm*? This is not mentioned anywhere in your question.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=c52925c99447da6ffa91c03c6ba7a358 please find this link.. the should start with last entered value, which is 70, but it picks different rows

Comment: sorry.. i missed by hurry, i edited my question later.. probably you might have missed my edit...

Comment: @pappu_kutty this is a **different** requirement than the one in your question. Post a new question where you explain what you want because by changing the requirement you invalidate the answers that you got.

Answer (score 0):

If you quantities are decreasing, then use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(total_quantity) over (order by created_dttm) as next_total_quantity
      from t
     ) t
where next_total_quantity is null or
      next_total_quantity <= 24;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bc58109c4cc3bbcbd55ef2dffb4f5b51) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: what lead() or lag() function does?

Comment: @pappu_kutty this answer does not return your expected results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=bce0a1b7b23a1c2d31666f06d978c464

Comment: @Gordon, can you comment on this..., in my pdAdmin, your solution works as expected, but forpas mentioned,, it is not working.. seems fishy here